# find examples of subspaces $w_1$ and $w_2$ of $R^3$ such that $dim (w_1) > dim(w_2)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find examples of subspaces $W_1$ and $W_2$ of $R^3$ such that $dim(w_1)$ >$dim(w_2)$ >$0$ and

a). $dim(w_1 \cap w_2)$ = $dim(w_2)$

b). $dim(w_1+w_2)$=$dim(w_1)$+$dim(w_2)$

c). $dim(w_1+w_2)$< $dim(w_1)+dim(w_2)$

For a). I have $w_1$= {$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$}, $w_2$={$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)$}

For b). $w_1$={$(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5)$}, $w_2$={$(4,5,6),(6,7,8)$}

For c). $w_1$={$(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$}, $w_2$={$(1,0,0),(1,2,3)$}

Are these correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the notation $\{v_1,v_2\}$ actually means the *span* of the given vectors.

---

a) is correct, however we don't need to mention the vector $(1,1,0)$ in $w_2$, as it's just the sum of the other two vectors.

b) is incorrect, both your $w_1$ and $w_2$ equal to $\mathrm{span}\{(1,2,3),\ (1,1,1)\}$.

c) is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get where you get (1,1,1). That is from c) I believe. I still can't anything wrong with b).

Comment: Look, we are working with *spans* of vectors, i.e. the sets of all possible linear combinations. And $(1,1,1) =(2,3, 4)-(1,2,3)$, so it is in $w_1$ of b) and similarly in $w_2$. Can you continue?

Comment: so does that mean since they both equal to (1,2,3), and (1,1,1) they are no longer linearly-independent?

Comment: Not exactly. But we get $span((1,2,3),\,(2,3,4),\,(3,4,5))=span((1,2,3),\, (1,1,1))=span((4,5,6),\,(1,1,1))=span((4,5,6),\,(6,7,8))$.